# styled components :hover with react-native and react-native-web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components, react-native-web

I'm using `styled-components` in React-Native App.
Let's say I have link component:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const Link = styled.Text`
  color: 'red';

  &:hover {
    color: 'blue';
  }
`
```

After that, I 'compile' my React-Native code with [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

All is great expect that hover is not working. (Text color remains `red` on hover.)

My guess is that https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native is removing the `hover` definition.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can ref to my answer in [onmouseenter event in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66204539/6318705)

Answer (score 7):

For native mobile development hover doesn't have a definition, that's because there is no cursor on the screen like there is on desktop devices. As React Native for web simulates how RN works, the :hover selector loose its sense

Comment: Probably 0.01% of the users tried this... you can have a mouse device connected to your phone or tablet. A pointer will show up like in traditional deckstops.

Answer (score 4):

You can use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave like in the refs section of styled-components. [Advanced guide](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [rn-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-css) that works like styled-components but with better support for css in React-Native.

Just replace `import styled from 'styled-components/native';` with `import styled from 'rn-css';` and your code will work.

Answer (score -1):

Try use TouchableHighlight.

You can define the backgroundcolor when your button it's pressed or not!

Follow the guide on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight

Comment: but that is onPress event. not hover event.