# onmouseenter event in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there a equivalent event in react native for 'onmouseenter'.
I have already tried pan responder and swipe-able

I want to detect if the user while swiping around a screen enters a component and leaves it.

Comment: What do you mean by entering a component and leaving a component ? are you talking about the touchable area of different components?

Comment: Yes, so lets say there is a View with width and height as 100, when a user is swiping around the screen(any part of it), if he enters the view and then if he leaves it, without lifting their finger. Just like a tooltip would do for a mouse pointer.

Comment: react-native-gesture-handler will be used for this.

Comment: already tried that, doesn't seem to have any thing for this

Comment: Then I don't think you will achieve what you want because most of the libraries based on it.

Comment: PanGestureHandler only works if you tab on that element first

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I need the same.

Comment: The idea is to get the current coordinates from PanResponder than match it to the View's coordinates based on its onLayout event information (x,y, width, height). More here:
https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/how-to-handle-user-gestures-in-react-native-with-panresponder

Comment: Yes, tried a similar approach, but since the elements in my project were angled there would always be some space left where it won't work. So, decided to not do it altogether

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the behavior of onMouseEnter with many code, in short, implemented a circle View as an indicator of the position where your finger touch the screen, and implemented the collision detection between the indicator circle and the component which you want onMouseEnter.

To compute pickerX and pickerY of the indicator circle, you can ref to what PanResponder did in https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-bitmap-color-picker/blob/master/index.js

To compute collision detection, you can ref to `areOverlapping = distanceBetweenCenters < circleDiameter` in https://dev.to/hrastnik/implementing-gravity-and-collision-detection-in-react-native-2hk5